# Does "relentless" imply something bad and not very bad?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Consider this [sentence](https://helloenglish.com/translate/english-Punjabi-dictionary/meaning-of-relentless-in-Punjabi/amp)

> It seemed he would never escape the relentless torture of being forced to choose a bride.

torture is bad though, this particular kind of torture (to choose a bride) is better than those real torture in real wars, right?

So, does "relentless" imply something bad and not very bad?

In other words, "relentless" usually is used in situations when things are not very bad?

Comment: What do the other examples in your link tell you about the term's connotations? Generally neutral, positive or negative? I think the answer is staring at you on that page. *Relentless* could be substituted with *endless* or *never ending* both of which are used to express the idea of something that continues "forever"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Relentless” by itself isn’t good or bad. It means something doesn’t end or someone doesn’t give up. For example, a relentless campaigner for human rights is someone who never gives up campaigning for human rights. A relentless thief is someone who steals and steals and steals without giving up.